# Vector layers without geometry in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, vector

I have set up a couple of automated layer additions via the toolbar.
After adding geometry in each respective layer (point, lineString, polygon) and saving changes to the layers, the added forms are non-present in the layers upon restart and reopening of files.

Additionally, to actually get 'run3' to pass and the layer to be added, the button has to be pressed twice to proceed through my `if statements`.  Which I don't clearly understand.

Please take error and non-Pythonic ways in the following code as a product of my novice skillset.

```
    # run add base
def run3(self):
    if FindDirectory._destination is 0:
        projectDirectory = bool(QgsProject.instance().readPath(''))
        if projectDirectory:
            projectDirectory = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")
            FindDirectory._destination = str(projectDirectory)
        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Please select a central folder location to save your base layer to!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=3)
    elif FindDirectory._destination is not 0:
        if GetMaps._TOPOcrs is 0:
            canvas = bool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
            if canvas:
                canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
                mapRenderer = canvas.mapRenderer()
                srs = mapRenderer.destinationCrs()
                GetMaps._TOPOcrs = str(srs.authid())
            else:
                iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Please select a topographic map for your simulation!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=3)
        elif GetMaps._TOPOcrs is not 0:
            crs = str(GetMaps._TOPOcrs)
            Base =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=' + GetMaps._TOPOcrs + '&field=BOTTOM:string(6)&field=TOP:string(6)&field=K:string(8)&field=Porosity:string(6)&field=Recharge:string(8)&field=IHead:string(5)&field=IBound:string(3)&index=yes', "Base", "memory")
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([Base])
            pr = Base.dataProvider()
            BaseFeat = FindDirectory._destination+"\Base.shp"
            writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(BaseFeat, "CP1250", pr.fields(), QGis.WKBPolygon, pr.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile" )
            iface.setActiveLayer(Base)
```